# Getting "includes is not a function" in Gulp

Tags: gulp

I'm new to Gulp. I wrote a function to parse the version in my `package.json` file like this

```
// Get the semver part of the version, e.g.,
// version = 1.4.31-p2, should return 1.4.31
function getSemVer(cb) {
  var semVer = pkg.version;
  if (semVer.includes("-")) {
    semVer = semVer.split("-")[0];
  }
  console.log(semVer);
  cb();
}
exports.getSemVer = getSemver
```

But when I run this I get an error

```
$ gulp getSemver -f gulpfiles/version.js
[22:56:58] Working directory changed to /path/gulpfiles
[22:56:59] Using gulpfile /path/gulpfiles/version.js
[22:56:59] Starting 'getSemVer'...
[22:56:59] 'getSemVer' errored after 1.53 ms
[22:56:59] TypeError: semVer.includes is not a function
    at getSemVer (/path/gulpfiles/version.js:27:14)
    at taskWrapper (/path/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (node:domain:416:15)
    at runBound (node:domain:427:12)
    at asyncRunner (/path/node_modules/async-done/index.js:55:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

I thought `includes()` a valid JavaScript function, shown in [JavaScript String includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp). What gives?

Comment: Which node.js version are you using? Node.js started supporting `String.prototype.includes` with version `4.0.0`.

Comment: You are - again - using a variable inside your function that seems undefined: `pkg`.

Comment: It’s an incomplete example, but is defined somewhere, otherwise I’d get that error.

Comment: `node -v` gives `v16.2.0` so yeah it should be there?